# How to change text of a SKLabelNode?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, sklabelnode

How do I update a label's text that was created in initWithSize?
Here is the code for the label within the initWithSize:

```
SKLabelNode *scoreLabel = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"TimesNewRoman"];
    scoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", score];
    scoreLabel.fontSize = 30;
    scoreLabel.position = CGPointMake(290, CGRectGetMidY(self.frame) - 30);
    scoreLabel.zRotation = -M_PI/2;
    [self addChild:scoreLabel];
```

As the game is running I update the variable score and I was just wondering how I can get the label to display the new score.

Comment: post the code how you are actually trying to change the label text, the errors you mention in comments indicate that the problem is in properly referencing the label object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to declare `scoreLabel` in the header file and then just so `scoreLabel.text = //Your text` anywhere you want.

EDIT:

In your .h file, declare
`@property (nonatomic,strong) SKLabelNode *scoreLabel;`

In your .m file, add
`@synthesize scoreLabel;`

When you are initializing the label do

`self.scoreLabel = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"TimesNewRoman"];`

and not

`SKLabelNode *scoreLabel = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"TimesNewRoman"];`

Comment: Thanks, but where would I add attributes like fontsize, position, etc? Because now I get a warning saying "local declaration of scoreLabel hides instance variable"

Comment: Whenever the score is update just call a method say :`adjustScoreLabel`. In that

` - (void)adjustScoreLabel{
        scoreLabel.text = //Your Text;
 scoreLabel.fontSize = //Your fontSize;
     scoreLabel.position = // Your position;
     // whatever attributes of the scoreLabel you want to change, add them here.
}`

Comment: I can edit scoreLabel.text but I get an error if I try to put scoreLabel.position or scoreLabel.fontsize. The error is "Property 'fontsize' not found on object of type UILabel." When I declare scoreLabel in the header file, I'm not actually creating the label on the screen am I?

Comment: No you are just declaring it in the header file. It is actually added to the screen when you do `[self.view addSubview:self.scoreLabel];`.Also, you are getting the error because there is no property called fontSize in UILabel.If you go to the SKLabelNode .h file, is a property called fontSize declared? If no, then to change the fontSize just do `self.scoreLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:/*fontName*/ size:/*fontSize*/];`

Answer (score 2):

Set retain/strong property for your SKLabelNode. then call any where from your app just

```
@Property(nonatomic,retain)SKLabelNode *scoreLabel;
```

if your score value has string

```
self.scoreLabel.Text=yourscore
```

if it is integer

```
self.scoreLabel.Text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [yourscore intValue]]];
```

Comment: If your adding the SKLabelNode to your SKScene then you can set the @property to weak as it will be retained by the SKScene when you add the label as a child.