# Displaying separate digits of a number in SKLabelNode Array Sprite kit

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, sklabelnode

I need to separate the digits of my score (in sprite kit game) and display them in SKLabelNodes independently. Is this possible. I may need to make a mutable array of sklabelnode but i am unable to do so. What i have achieved till now is this:-

```
NSMutableArray *digits = [NSMutableArray array];

for(int i = 0; score ; i++){
    [digits addObject: [NSNumber numberWithInt:score%10]];
    score /= 10;
    NSLog(@"digits : %@", digits);
}
```

I have separated the digits. I don't know how should i get them displayed in separate SKLabelNodes. help?

Comment: What was the output you have got@swati

Comment: I am getting separate digits of my score. Eg if my score is 340, I am getting 3 elements in my digits array as in 3, 4, and 0

Comment: Once check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21621309/how-to-change-text-of-a-sklabelnode

Comment: my problem has been solved. Saw one of answers in stack overflow. Thanks anyways..